# Npm Module Error In Mocha Test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js

I trying to get 'mocha' to run on my build. However, I am getting the following error in CLI:

```
> wym-app@0.52.0 mocha /var/www/wym/wym-app_main
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha "lib/*.spec.js" --compilers js:babel-    core/register --recursive

module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'apiConfig'
....
```

A few points:

- Mocha is installed both locally & globally
- My webpack build works fine
- Mocha global version is 3.1.2
- devDependencies installed are:

  ```
  "babel-cli": "^6.7.5",
  "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.6.5",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
  "cross-env": "^1.0.8",
  "mocha": "^2.5.3",
  ...
  ```
- My package.json has the following command for running the mocha test:

  "mocha": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha \"lib/*.spec.js\" --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
- Directory path looks something like this:

  ...

  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js
  - lib/

    - index.js
    - index.spec.js